# Link not working on image button

Tags: html, css

I have image buttons that change appearance on hover by changing the content of the image in CSS. Not sure if that is part of the problem but for some reason when I click on my image link nothing happens.

Here's the code I am using:

```
<div class="hub-background">
    <div class="hub-container"> 
        <article class="btn-twitch">
            <a href="twitch.tv/destifly">; 
            <img src=" ***** "> </a> 
        </article> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Include the code in the post please.

Comment: i cant.. i already wrote that. i cant post code with images and the links are so long for the images that it cant be properly formatted. I included a link for a reason.

Comment: Post your code as text.

Comment: fine ill put it here in comments.

Comment: Add your code to your question. Also, don't include an insult as your opening statement, that is going to draw unneeded negative attention to your question.

Comment: <div class="hub-background">
    <div class="hub-container">
        <article class="btn-twitch">
         <a href="https://twitch.tv/destifly">
             <img src=" ***** ">
         </a>
        </article>
    </div>
</div>

this is just one small chunk of it.. but its all for one button

Comment: .hub-background {
    background-image: url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/simbla-static/2017/2/57e2bc5f559c3dae27ffc585/31670-lhz5fu.png");
    background-size: auto 100vh;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
}
.hub-container{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center; 

    margin-top: 0vh;
    height: 100vh;
}


CSS Part 1

Comment: You should create a working JSFiddle or Codepen so we can see the code in action. We need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to help. If you really want help, don't start by bad mouthing StackOverflow and also realize that we are here on our own volution to help others. I understand programming can be very frustrating, but take time to learn the rules and respect those who are offering their help to you.

Comment: whats jsfiddle and codepen. 

(also im no programmer, im an animator, 3d modeler and photoshop artist, just outright dont have the patience for code but left with no choice)

Comment: A simple Google search will answer that question for you

Comment: ya i found it. heres the link.. it looks kinda broken in jsfiddle but perfectly fine on my website. Dont know how to fix that. sry

https://jsfiddle.net/u4n2osd8/

Comment: it might be easier to see what im having issues with if you just check my actual website... heres the link to the page im having issues with.

http://triggergamestudios.net/dashboard

Comment: @AshlieWilliams-TGS You recently posted an answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43123575/trying-to-find-a-way-to-make-a-gap-between-menu-and-dropdown-boxes), only to delete it seconds later. The down-votes are not related directly to being novice, but to not reading and/or applying [ask] (and [answer]). Make sure you read, understand and apply those guidelines and I can assure your questions will be welcome. As a matter of fact, the more reputation a user has, the higher the requirements from their questions (in general), in terms of research effort and overall quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the article inside of the anchor tag

```
<div class="hub-background">
  <div class="hub-container"> 
    <a href="...">
      <article class="btn-twitch">
        <img src="..."> 
      </article> 
    </a> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: THANKYOU!!>.....

i hate that i come here to get help... put it out front that .. i cant code for crap. nor do i really have any interest in it (forced to do it right now) and all i get for asking somthing is getting shit on. ... i remember when this site wasent ruled by a rep and points system.. what ever happend to those days (actually i might be thinking of a different site... but if i am.. then its basically the same thing)

Comment: @AshlieWilliams-TGS - Sorry you feel that way, but you should probably change your expectations about what SO is. [You've come to a place for "professional and enthusiast programmers"](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and even said yourself "i cant code for crap. **nor do i really have any interest in it**" - being bad/new at programming is fine, but blatantly signalling that you have no interest in learning programming frustrates experts that come here to altruistically teach others programming.