# Trying to find a way to make a gap between Menu and Dropdown boxes

Tags: html, css

So basically im trying to put a small gap under my menu bar to make space for the underline that is part of the background behind it. (3px thick) I know this is probably a really simple fix but im not sure how to do it. Just starting to learn code so i can make a website to use as a portfolio/blog.

```css
.main-ul {
    background: #070707 !important;
    z-index: 9999 !important;
    list-style-type: none !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    
    -webkit-transition: 0.25s;
 transition: 0.25s;
} 
.main-li {
    z-index: 9999 !important;
    float: left !important;
} /*
.main-li a {
    display: inline-block !important;
    color: #eee !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    padding: 8px 16px 12px 16px !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    font: "open sans" !important;
    font-weight: 100 !important;
    line-height: 30px !important;
    border-bottom: solid 3px transparent !important;
}
.main-li a:hover {
    display: inline-block !important;
    vertical-align: middle;
    
    -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0) !important;
    transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0) !important;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent !important;
    position: relative !important;
    -webkit-transition-property: color !important;
    transition-property: color !important;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s !important;
    transition-duration: 0.3s !important;
    
    color: #437dff !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    font: "open sans" !important;
    font-weight: 100 !important;
    padding: 8px 16px 12px 16px !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    line-height: 30px !important;
}
.main-li a:active {
    display: inline-block !important;
    color: #eee !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    font: "open sans" !important;
    font-weight: 100 !important;
    padding: 8px 16px 12px 16px !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    line-height: 30px !important;
    border-bottom: solid 3px #437dff !important;
}
/* DROPDOWN STYLES */
.main-li:hover .dropdown {
    display: block !important;
}
.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
    
    z-index: 9999 !important;
    display: none !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    background-color: #191d26 !important;
    min-width: 160px !important;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 25px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2) !important;
    color: #eee !important;
    transition: 0.1s !important;
}
.dropdown:hover {
    z-index: 9999 !important;
    display: none !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    min-width: 160px !important;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 25px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2) !important;
    
    transition: 0.1s !important;
}
.dropdown a {
    color: #eeeeee !important;
    padding: 6px 8px !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    display: block !important;
    text-align: left !important;
    border-bottom: solid 0px transparent !important;
    
    font-size: 14px !important;
    font-weight: 100 !important;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px !important;
    
 transition: 0.1s !important;
}
.dropdown a:hover {
    color: #000 !important;
    padding: 6px 8px !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    display: block !important;
    text-align: left !important;
    border-bottom: solid 0px transparent !important;
    color: #eee !important;
    background-color: #222733 !important;

 transition: 0.25s !important;
}
/* sweep to bottom */
.main-li a {
    display: inline-block !important;
    color: #eee !important;
    text-align: center !important;   
    vertical-align: middle !important;
    
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    padding: 20px 16px 12px 16px !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    font: "open sans" !important;
    font-weight: 100 !important;
    line-height: 30px !important;
    border-bottom: solid 0px transparent !important;

    -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0) !important;
    transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0) !important;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent !important;
    position: relative !important;
    -webkit-transition-property: color !important;
    transition-property: color !important;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s !important;
    transition-duration: 0.3s !important;
}
.main-li a:before {
    content: "" !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    z-index: -1 !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    right: 0 !important;
    bottom: 0 !important;
    background: #6441A4 !important;
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0) !important;
    transform: scaleY(0) !important;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100% !important;
    transform-origin: 50% 100% !important;
    -webkit-transition-property: transform !important;
    transition-property: transform !important;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s !important;
    transition-duration: 0.3s !important;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out !important;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out !important;
}
.main-li a:hover, .main-li a:focus, .main-li a:active {
  color: white !important;
}
.main-li a:hover:before, .main-li a:focus:before, .main-li a:active:before {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1) !important;
    transform: scaleY(1) !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- HTML LAYOUT -->
    <ul class="main-ul">
        <!-- ABOUT BUTTON -->
        <li class="main-li">
            <a href="">ABOUT</a>
        </li>
        <!-- COMMUNITY BUTTON -->
        <li class="main-li">
            <a href="">COMMUNITY</a>
            <!-- COMMUNITY DROPDOWNS -->
            <div class="dropdown">
                <a href="">News</a>
                <a href="">YoutTube</a>
                <a href="">Forums</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <!-- STORE BUTTON -->
        <li class="main-li">  
            <a href="">STORE</a>
        </li>
        <!-- HELP BUTTON -->
        <li class="main-li">
            <a href="">HELP</a>
            <!-- HELP DROPDOWNS -->
            <div class="dropdown">
                    <a href="">Asset Store</a>
                    <a href="">Game Mods</a>
      </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

NOTE - The menu wont work on my site without the !important declarations because im using an editor and its not meant for you to make your own menu, rather just pick one from their super crappy templates.

Heres what i have so far. Its kinda broken when you hover over the dropdowns but i already know how to fix that so thats not much of a worry for me.

Comment: The first thing you want to do is remove all the `!important` declarations in your `CSS`. It's the only way you'll be able to understand how `CSS` specificity works and get to a working solution.

Comment: as i said.. i cant remove the !important declarations.. i know its bad code... but because im using an editor that has hardcoded css that affects my menu... without the importants it is completely broken. Your expected to use a premade template with a premade menu bar

Comment: I see. I can assure you a lot less people will be willing to help you with this code, for this reason alone, me included. But I'm sure the creators of your editor will be very happy to help. Best of luck!

Comment: Seriously... why is everyone on this site so unhelpful to novice coders. I'm stuck and asking for help and all i get are down votes and figurative slaps to the face. ... cant help but wonder if ill ever meet a programmer who is genuinely nice and helps others because they can.

Oh and lol you think the creators will help... HA.. last time i asked for help they said sorry not our problem go away.

Comment: @Destifly It has nothing to do with being novice. It has to do with not reading, not understanding or not applying the guidelines outlined in [ask]. As a matter of fact, novice are, statistically speaking, getting less down-votes for the same mistakes. As your rep grows, people start having higher expectations in terms of overall quality and research effort from your questions. In short, the more novice you are the more forgiving other users are to you. They look for reasons to upvote your actions. Just give them a few, that's all.

Comment: You should at least learn the following: it is a lot harder to reverse the vote balance for a question that was initially very low quality and later on improved. I know it's not fair, but it's how things work, because people vote and leave, they're not announced anything like: *"this post you downvoted was edited, care to revise your vote?"*. That, unfortunately, doesn't happen. So it is a lot better to post a well researched question in the first place, following the guidelines I already pointed to.

Comment: I just read the 'How to Ask' section that you linked. I didn't understand a single one of the examples or what they meant. As for the rest... believe me... this was the condensed and shortened version. If if i was talking in person... id ramble for a good half hour at least about something as simple as this. (I don't really know how to be short and concise with questions... or anything)

Comment: I can tell you your question looks a lot better than before, just because you provided a [mcve]. In fact, that and a minimal research are most times enough. It's also a very good idea to mention and specify any similar questions/resources that don't help and why they don't (if you know). It enables others to point you in the right direction, or underline the principle you're not getting a lot faster/with less effort. It all comes down to: how much time do I need to invest in this answer compared to how much the OP invested in asking/researching. Answerers here are trying to help, voluntarily.

Comment: Ok true I see your point. I cant take any credit for the code snippet though... it just showed up in my inbox as a suggested edit.  I tried for like 15 minutes to get it to say it was a valid code snip but couldn't. No idea what i was doing wrong.
 
Would it be possible at all to use css to just shift ".dropdown" downward by 3px? Without using padding or margin?

Comment: I understand a minimal technical level is required in order to use the site properly. But I promise you the effort to get there pays off. This website/community is intended/aimed at helping programmers get better at coding, not at providing free of charge answers for small requirements from clients not having a clue on how to code. I'm sure you'll get there. All you need is a bit of effort and and some patience. Good luck!

Comment: Not to interrupt Andrei's very good advice session. 
Try defining your css more specifically eg. `html body #content #navbar .main-ul` Better than just `.main-ul`. Additionally I'm not sure what your OP is asking. I understand you want a 3px gap somewhere under the main navbar which you could do with `.main-ul { border-bottom: #F00 3px solid; }` but do you want the submenus to overlap that bar? or have the 3px always show? or `.main-li {margin-bottom: 3px} .main-li a:before { bottom: 3px }` Can you please clarify?

Comment: Sure.. here the best way i can explain is by showing you the whole code which includes the code for the drag and drop elements from the editor.

heres the link to it http://scratchpad.io/smooth-planes-

in short.. i need a way to force the 'dropdown' section to start 3px lower then where it is now. but without using margin or padding as that just makes the header taller.

Comment: crap.. accidentally messed up the link when i fixed a typo .. here.

http://scratchpad.io/smooth-planes-9607

Comment: To start, on that link change this `.main-li:hover .dropdown {
    display: block !important;

}` to `.main-li:hover .dropdown {
    display: block !important;
    margin-top: 3px;
}` you'll notice that the 3 pixel gap will make you drop hover so you sometimes lose the submenu when you go from the top to the bottom menu because your background colour is from your `header` instead of your `main-ul` div. You may want to re-jig the css so that the gap is closed somehow.